# Elasticsearch change field date format

Tags: elasticsearch

When i created my index and type a while ago I specified the date format of a field in the mapping as:

```
{"type": "date","format" : "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"}
```

Is there a way to change the format of the field knowing that now i have more than 6000 docs indexed in my index ? I want the format to be:

```
{"type": "date","format" : "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change field mappings after you have indexed documents into Elasticsearch. You can add new fields but you cannot change existing fields.

You could create a new index with the new mappings and then re-index all the data into it. You could then delete the old index and create a new index alias with the old name point to the new index.

There are a few strategies documented for minimizing downtime when changing mappings in the Elasticsearch blog: https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime

Overall I'd highly suggest using index aliases - they provide a high level of abstraction and flexibility over using index names directly within your application. Perfect for situations like this where you want to make a change to the underlying index: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html

Comment: The format mapping is one of the few mappings that can be updated on an existing field with the PUT mapping API, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/mapping-date-format.html

Answer (score 4):

You can update format mapping on an existing date field with the PUT mapping API:

```
PUT twitter/_mapping/user 
{
  "properties": {
    "myDate": {
      "format": "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    }
  }
}
```

*format* is one of the few mappings that can be updated on existing fields without losing data

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/mapping-date-format.html

Comment: I tried this. It complained "myDate has no type", so I added `"type": "date"`. Then it complained `mapper for [myDate] conflicts with existing mapping in other types`. So I don't think your solution works at all.

Comment: Maybe disabled as part of this: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/25271

Answer (score 2):

For elastic version <7.0 where mapping type is not deprecated

you can use something like this

```
PUT inf/_mapping/_doc 
{
  "properties": {
    "ChargeDate": {
      "type":"date",
      "format": "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    }
  }
}
```

where inf is your `index and _doc` is mapping type(which is deprecated in v >`7.0)`

or

```
PUT inf
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "ChargeDate": {
         "type":"date",
      "format": "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```